# using beautiful soup to check if item is in stock

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use beautiful soup to set up a page monitor to see when specific sizes of a shoe are back in stock. Looking at the page's [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHN0L.jpg)

The `is-unavailable` class looks to indicate that particular size is not in stock, and not having that class means the size is in stock. However, when I use `soup.find_all('li',class_='is-unavailable')` nothing is returned.

When I use `soup.find_all('li',class_='btn--large')` the class `is-unavailable` is not in the list of classes, even though the size is sold out.

`[<li class="js-product__size sizes-list__item btn btn--large "...`

Any idea why this is the case, or how to generate sizes that are unavailable using Beautiful Soup?

Comment: Give the prefix `js-` in the class, it's possible the content is dynamically loaded through Javascript - standard modules do not handle this. Try reading the html with [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: To add to the comment posted by @Wondercricket, you can check what kind of data is available in the basic HTML by using the "view source" feature of your browser instead of the developer console.

Comment: Another alternative to selenium is dryscrape